# Enviar varios parametros por args [JAVA]

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo java y me gustaría resolver este problema

Tengo un programa que ejecuta 2 subprocesos (Hijo1 e Hijo2) los cuales les envio datos a través de un fichero (fichero1) y con un redirect devuelvo el resultado a otro fichero (fichero2) al ejecutar el programa por bash quiero añadir un "-p" para indicar los procesos a ejecutar y después "-a" para indicar los archivos resultantes, algo así:

> java Padre -p Hijo1 Hijo2 -a fichero1.txt fichero2.txt

No tengo problema con el código, ya que funciona correctamente pero me gustaría usar ese "-p" para indicar los procesos y "-a" para indicar las rutas de los archivos.

Probablemente sea algo muy sencillo pero no estoy muy familiarizado con args.

Habia pensado en un bucle leyendo todos los args con args.length y buscar que argumento es "-p" o "-a" con args[i].equals("-p") pero ahi me quedo estancado

Answer (score 0):

Hace un tiempo [hice una aplicación](https://github.com/killbunny/PurgaIMAP/blob/master/PurgarIMAP/Program.cs) en consola que recibía algunos parámetros de entrada. La aplicación está en C# pero creo que se puede traducir a Java facilemente.

Lo que hago es obtener todas las cadenas que vienen en el arreglo args[] e iterar buscando las lineas de argumento `"-X"` seguido de su valor `args[( argumentoEncontrado)+1]`

El snippet es algo así:

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            string ayudastr = "Parámetros de entrada\n"+
             "Param     Descripción\n"+
             " -h       Ayuda. Este texto\n"+
             " -r       Solo mostrar (No eliminar)\n" +
             " -v       Verbose, salida a consola del detalle del proceso\n"+
             " -q       No pedir confirmaciones.\n" +
             " -e       Pedir confirmación para eliminar.\n" +
             " -u '' *  Usuario del cliente\n"+
             " -p '' *  Contraseña del cliente\n"+
             " -S '' *  Host IMAP\n"+
             " -P ''    Puerto del host\n"+
             " -s       Usar SSL\n" +
             " -T       Usar TLS\n" +
             " -d '' *  Días atrás a eliminar\n"+
             " -f '' *  Carpeta donde buscar mensajes. Case sensitive."; 
            foreach (string s in args)
                Console.Write(s + " ");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            int iUsr=-1, iPass=-1, iServer=-1, iDias=-1, iFolder=-1, iPuerto=-1;
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Count(); i++)
                switch (args[i])
                {
                    case "-u":
                        iUsr = i + 1;
                        break;
                    case "-p":
                        iPass = i + 1;
                        break;
                    case "-P":
                        iPuerto = i + 1;
                        break;
                    case "-S":
                        iServer = i + 1;
                        break;
                    case "-d":
                        iDias = i + 1;
                        break;
                    case "-f":
                        iFolder = i + 1;
                        break;
                }
            if (args.Contains("-h"))
            {
                Console.Write(ayudastr);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            string user = "";
            string pass = "";
            string server = "";
            double dias = 0;
            string fechastr = "";
            string folderemail = "";
            try
            {
                user = args[iUsr];
                pass = args[iPass];
                server = args[iServer];
                dias = -1 * Convert.ToDouble(args[iDias]);
                fechastr = DateTime.Now.AddDays(dias).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                folderemail = args[iFolder];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Faltan parámetros necesarios");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            string puerto = "993";//IMAP default
            bool verbose = false;
            bool useSSL = false;
            bool useTLS = false;
            bool validarCert = false;
            bool pedirConfirmacionEliminar = false;
            bool pedirConfirmacion = false;
            bool soloMostrar = false;
            if (iPuerto != -1)
                puerto = args[iPuerto];
            if (args.Contains("-s"))
                useSSL = true;
            if (args.Contains("-T"))
                useTLS = true;
            if (args.Contains("-r"))
                soloMostrar = true;
            if (args.Contains("-e"))
                pedirConfirmacionEliminar = true;
            if (args.Contains("-q"))
                pedirConfirmacion= true;
```

Seguramente hay maneras mas faciles de hacerlo pero esta es la que me funcionó en su momento.